# Error: premature end of file for XML document?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have to generate XML and XSD from this diagram:

[image: diagram]

But an **error: premature end of file** pops up.
I also encounter another **error: xsd:all must terminate with end tag** 
Is my code correct?

**Entity Relation Constraints:**

```
1. A theater can have at least 1 screen but not more than 3. 
2. A screen may have many shows and sometimes it may not have any show. 
   show-time example - 10 AM, 12 PM etc. 
3. A show has information on the movie which has the director name, title 
   and the release date which can occur in any order. 
4. A movie will have actors and actors may have many actor's name.
```

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<theater>
<name>rajat</name>
<address>mumbai</address>
<phone>987654</phone>
    <screen>
        <seats>30</seats>
        <width>30</width>
            <show>
                <show-time>10 AM</show-time>
                    <movie>
                        <director>jade</director>
                        <title>game</title>
                        <release-date>10/10/2017</release-date>
                            <actors>
                                <name>james</name>
                                <name>aaron</name>
                            </actors>
                    </movie>
            </show>
    </screen>
</theater>
```

**XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:element name="theater">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="address" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="phone" type="xsd:long"/>
    <xsd:element name="screen" maxOccurs="3"/>                
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="seats" type="xsd:byte"/>
    <xsd:element name="width" type="xsd:byte"/>
    <xsd:element name="show" minOccurs="0"/>
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="show-time" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
    minOccurs="0"/>
    <xsd:element name="movie"/>
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:all>
    <xsd:element name="director" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="release-date" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="actors"/>
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
    minOccurs="0"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence> 
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Your XML is valid, if that's what you're asking. You haven't provided the code that's supposed to read it.

Comment: I have added the xsd as well. Basically I have to generate both XML as well as XSD

Comment: Your XSD is *not* valid. Use an editor with highlighting and proper indenting. You've got several mismatched open/close tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

```
xmlns:xsd="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

must instead be

```
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

**Second:**

```
    <xsd:element name="screen" maxOccurs="3"/>
      <xsd:complexType>
```

must instead be

```
    <xsd:element name="screen" maxOccurs="3">
      <xsd:complexType>
```

The above type of error occurs in multiple places.

**Third:**

Finally, use an XML editor and balance your closing tags.

---

Altogether, here is your XSD fixed to be syntactically valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="theater">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="address" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="phone" type="xsd:long"/>
        <xsd:element name="screen" maxOccurs="3">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="seats" type="xsd:byte"/>
              <xsd:element name="width" type="xsd:byte"/>
              <xsd:element name="show" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="show-time" type="xsd:string" 
                                 maxOccurs="unbounded" 
                                 minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="movie">
                      <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:all>
                          <xsd:element name="director" type="xsd:string"/>
                          <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
                          <xsd:element name="release-date" type="xsd:string"/>
                          <xsd:element name="actors">
                          <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                              <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" 
                                           maxOccurs="unbounded" 
                                           minOccurs="0"/>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                          </xsd:complexType>
                          </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:all>
                      </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                  </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Validation against your XML document is left as an exercise for you to do.

Comment: Silly errors from my side. Thank you for your help. I have solved the problem now :)